# Scraping Yield value from Meusdividendos.com to google sheets Importxml Xpath

Tags: xpath, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to do scraping of yield value, as I am not being able to do it with google finance for some reason, the codes i have been trying are some thing like this. Cell B14 contains 'ITSA4'.

```
=ImportXML(CONCAT("https://www.meusdividendos.com/acao/";B14);"//*[@class='table table-hover']/tr[3]/td[2]/span")
```

Returns :

```
50.132.874.015.748.000,00
```

Another try :

```
=ImportXML(CONCAT("https://www.meusdividendos.com/acao/";B14);"//*[@id='perfil']//span[@*]/text()")
```

Returns :

```
Volume
330300
17110079173999900
625052415887850000%
6.68
16.79
```

Please let me know if you have any thought or solution for me to get this value out of the web site.

Images for reference :

[The exact value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMNAZ.png)
[Meusdividedos website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l09y7.png)

**EDITE 2**
Using your last code, the one that should be flawless I am getting this erros message `Error Function REGEXREPLACE parameter 1 expects text values. But '0' is a number and cannot be coerced to a text.`
I tried putting in different areas like Europe and USA, and also did not work.

What it is odd to me, is that a system which is Online like google sheets, is giving 2 different results for the same formula.

**Edit 3**

Right now started working again, on the left side we have a straight copy or the spreadsheet you gave me, the 2 last rows were still updating, just so you can see what its going on. On the right side i am using the last Code you gave me, as you can see, still have the same issue.

[EDIT 3 Spread sheet working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEtEp.png)

Comment: Why the last formula doesn't work : the data returned by the `IMPORTXML` formula is a number, not a text. In that case you have to use the first formula (the one used on the left side) to display correctly the data, which as you can see, works. Just to be sure, could you post the 2 type of data output you get with `IMPORTXML` only ? For example : `0.04945145631067962` (which needs the first forrmula) or `4.945.145.631.067.962,00` (which needs the last formula).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following XPath to extract the value of interest :

```
//span[@class='pull-right converter-percentual']
```

To display it correctly in Google Sheets, use the following formula :

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML(C5;"//span[@class='pull-right converter-percentual']");".";","))
```

Be sure to set the format of the cell to "percentage".

Output (I've tested the previous formula with 10 other market shares) :

[image: Acao]

EDIT :

If you want to keep your logic (concat root url + ident of the market share) and one of your original XPath (corrected), use :

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML("https://www.meusdividendos.com/acao/"&B14;"//*[@class='table table-hover']//tr[3]/td[2]/span");".";","))
```

**EDIT 2** :

Well, that's odd, the same formula outputs no error in my sheet (I've tested it with a portuguese setting). I'm based in Europe.

[image: Br]

I think that's because `IMPORTXML` doesn't return the same string : `0.04945145631067962` in my case, `4.945.145.631.067.962` in yours.

So you have to change the formula. Instead `SUBSTITUTE`, use `REGEXREPLACE`.

```
=VALOR(REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTXML(B2;"//span[@class='pull-right converter-percentual']");"^(\d+)\.(\d{3})\.(\d{3})\.(\d{3})\.(\d{3})\.(\d{3})";"$1,$2$3$4$5$6"))
```

Output :

[image: Solution]

Note : setting the cell to percentage format is not needed now. Just set the number of digits to 2 (*casas decimals*).

**EDIT 3** :

First of all, using `VALUE` and `SUBSTITUTE` is not mandatory. Without it, you'll get the raw data in the cell. So, with :

```
IMPORTXML(B2;"//span[@class='pull-right converter-percentual']")
```

You will get `4.945.145.631.067.962`. `VALUE` and `SUBSTITUTE` are used to format the raw data and display `4,95 %`.

Let's use something else to display correctly the data. Keep your regional settings as they are (Brazil). And use the following formula :

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTXML(B2;"//span[@class='pull-right converter-percentual']");"[\.,]";"|");"|";",";1);"|";""))
```

This should work flawlessly now.

**EDIT 4** :

Use the following formula to add a security layer :

```
=IFERROR(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML(B2;"//span[@class='pull-right converter-percentual']");".";","));VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTXML(B2;"//span[@class='pull-right converter-percentual']");"[\.,]";"|");"|";",";1);"|";"")))
```

[Sheet for reference](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xY4WUBf2R0lb7ibDk-5tCm7-EUEi2rKrHNoDibpSQAI/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @E.Wiest however still giving me errors would you know if is something wrong in the setting of my google sheets? I even opened a blank sheet and set to percentage, and still giving error boths ways. I will show the image in the next post.

Comment: Actually would me nice if you could share that sheet with me so I can check why my sheets are not working, and yours are. mgpaixao@gmail.com

Comment: Post have been edited with a solution. And a link to my sheet.:)

Comment: Post is edited with an alternative solution. It should be OK now. If it doesn't, please post the raw value return by the `IMPORTXML` formula (without `VALUE` and `SUBSTITUTE`). One last thing : use edit system to add information to YOUR original question (not my answer). And comment system to ask for details, clarifications, or respond to a posted answer.

Comment: I posted the update on the last error message I got. Thanks for helping me here, Its my first time using stackoverflow and I am still getting  to know my way around.

Comment: Hello, I posted another update on the issue. Edit 3

Comment: OK. I've answered in the comments and edited *hopefully* my post for the last time (See `EDIT 4`).:)